# Changing the color of a String in android(with parse.com implementation)

Tags: android, string, colors, parse-platform

In my app i am using parse.com to import multiple string values and list them in a list view

see image -  http://postimg.org/image/onpyj0ro5/

My aim here is to change the color of the two String values shown in the above image  programatically (not in .xml files)

I have tried implementing SpannableString & SpannableStringBuilder but had no success.

.xml files:

listview_main_wednesday.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_wednesday"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

listview_item_wednesday.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:padding="5sp"
android:textSize="15sp" 
android:textColor="@color/list_background"

/>
```

my fragment code

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

    listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview_wednesday);      
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_wednesday);


    for (ParseObject country : ob) {



        adapter.add((String) country.get("pSubject") + "\n" + "\n" + (String)   country.get("pTime"):

    }  

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);       
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();  
    }

 }
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: cant you get the get the text view by id and set text color on it?

Comment: I think you will need to create a custom adapter. That way you can access the `textView` individually. Unless you want them all changed the same

Comment: I am considering this, my fear is that would take to much time to implement, unfortunately time is not on my side. Do you know of any examples/tutorials that are out there that could help?

Comment: Finally got an adapter working, was the only way to go, changing colours and doing all sorts of crazy stuff now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

first get the text view,

```
TextView textView1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

and then,

```
textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))
```

or

```
textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

or

```
 textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
 textView1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
```

is this what you want?

you can use [this](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/) to implement simple custom adapter.

Comment: The textview in the listview item never actually has a value displayed. it acts as a container for the string values.